# Expandable list not working in android app

Tags: java, android

I am trying to implement expandable list in my activity but it only shows the first item. it is not showing the rest items in headlist and on click listener is showing toast when i change the code but it is not showing the list in first header. i am new to android. cant figure it out as it is not showing any logcat error.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter;
ExpandableListView expListView;
List<String> listDataHeader;
HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild;
ArrayList<item> list1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    // get the listview
    expListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.lvExp);

    // preparing list data
    prepareListData();

    listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(this, listDataHeader, listDataChild);

    // setting list adapter
    expListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
}

private void prepareListData() {
    listDataHeader = new ArrayList<String>();
    listDataChild = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

    // Adding child data
    listDataHeader.add("Cat1");
    listDataHeader.add("Cat2");
    listDataHeader.add("Cat3");

    // Adding child data
    List<String> Cat1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    Cat1.add("Item 1");
    Cat1.add("Item 2");
    Cat1.add("Item 3");
    Cat1.add("Item 4");
    Cat1.add("Item 5");
    Cat1.add("Item 6");
    Cat1.add("Item 7");

    List<String> Cat2 = new ArrayList<String>();
    Cat2.add("item2 1");
    Cat2.add("item2 2");
    Cat2.add("item2 3");
    Cat2.add("item2 4");
    Cat2.add("item2 5");
    Cat2.add("item2 6");

    List<String> Cat3 = new ArrayList<String>();
    Cat3.add("item3 1");
    Cat3.add("item3 2");
    Cat3.add("item3 3");
    Cat3.add("item3 4");
    Cat3.add("item3 5");

    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(0), Cat1); // Header, Child data
    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(1), Cat2);
    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(2), Cat3);
}
```

}

```
public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

private Context _context;
private List<String> _listDataHeader; // header titles
// child data in format of header title, child title
private HashMap<String, List<String>> _listDataChild;

public ExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<String> listDataHeader,
                             HashMap<String, List<String>> listChildData) {
    this._context = context;
    this._listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
    this._listDataChild = listChildData;
}

@Override
public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosititon) {
    return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
            .get(childPosititon);
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return childPosition;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
                         boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
    }

    TextView txtListChild = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.lblListItem);

    txtListChild.setText(childText);
    return convertView;
}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
            .size();
}

@Override
public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
    return this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
}

@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    return this._listDataHeader.size();
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
    return groupPosition;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                         View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_group, null);
    }

    TextView lblListHeader = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.lblListHeader);
    lblListHeader.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
    lblListHeader.setText(headerTitle);

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return true;
}
```

}

Comment: It is not showing list in first header only or all the headers? Share screenshots if possible.

Comment: it is not showing list in any header. the only thing it shows is first element of the header ie cat1 nothing else